# Outlook 2010 Calendar Week View alternative

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to view the calendar by week with the days running top to bottom and the time-of-day running left to right? The default is the inverse of this but I find this would be better for my monitor setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get a bit in your direction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>:

[image]